# error en proyecto de microservicio acortador de urls de FreeCodeCamp

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, rest, moongose

me encuentro haciendo un proyecto backend de la pagina FreeCodeCamp.org, por favor si alguien ya lo ha pasado me podría ayudar a pasarlo.

Mi proyecto funciona perfectamente cuando lo pruebo localmente, tambien funciona bien si lo pruebo en la página replit.com, un constructor de sitios,con el siguiente enlace por si quieren probarlo: https://FCC-Shortener-Microservice.monkaws624.repl.co,

El problema está en cuando introduzco dicha url al campo para realizar los tests en FCC, solo paso el primer test, y falla en los demás.

Esto es lo que debería pasar:

1. Debes proporcionar tu propio proyecto, no la URL de ejemplo.
2. Puedes hacer un POST de una URL a /api/shorturl, la cual se hace escribiendo una url válida en el campo de texto y dar clic al boton 'POST URL' y obtener una respuesta JSON con las propiedades original_url y short_url. Este es un ejemplo: { original_url : 'https://freeCodeCamp.org', short_url : 1}
3. Cuando visite /api/shorturl/<short_url>, será redirigido a la URL original.
4. Si pasas una URL no válida que no sigue el formato válido de http://www.example.com, la respuesta JSON contendrá { error: 'invalid url' }

Este es el codigo:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const dns = require('dns')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const router = express.Router

// Basic Configuration
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true})

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function(){
  console.log("conectado a la BD!")
})

app.use(cors());

app.use('/public', express.static(`${process.cwd()}/public`));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))

app.use(bodyParser.json())

const urlScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
  original_url: String,
  short_url: String
});

let urlModel = mongoose.model('url', urlScheme)

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(process.cwd() + '/views/index.html');
});

// Store url in database
app.post('/api/shorturl', function(req, res){
  const myRegex= /https:\/\/(www.)?|http:\/\/(www.)?/g;

  const bodyOfRequest = req.body.url

  dns.lookup(req.body.url.replace(myRegex, ""), (err, address, family) => {
    if(err || !myRegex.test(bodyOfRequest)){
      res.json({
        "error": "invalid url"
      })
    }
    else{
      const myRandomId = parseInt(Math.random() * 999999)
      urlModel
      .find()
      .exec()
      .then(data => {
        new urlModel({
          original_url: bodyOfRequest,
          short_url: myRandomId
        })
        .save()
        .then(()=>{
          res.json({
            original_url: bodyOfRequest,
            short_url: myRandomId
          })
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.json(err)
        })
      })
    }
  })
})

// Get url from DB and redirect
app.get('/api/shorturl/:number', function(req, res){
  urlModel
  .find({
    short_url: req.params.number
  })
  .exec()
  .then((url)=>{    
    res.redirect(url[0]["original_url"]);
  });
})

// Your first API endpoint
app.get('/api/hello', function(req, res) {
  res.json({ greeting: 'hello API' });
});

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

En la consola de replit, me sale este error cuando FCC está haciendo los tests:

```
> shorturl@0.0.3 start
> node index.js

Listening on port 8080
conectado a la BD!
/home/runner/FCC-Shortener-Microservice/index.js:87
    res.redirect(url[0].original_url);
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'original_url')
    at /home/runner/FCC-Shortener-Microservice/index.js:87:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
exit status 1

BadRequestError: request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.onAborted (/home/runner/FCC-Shortener-Microservice/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:238:10)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at IncomingMessage._destroy (node:_http_incoming:179:10)
    at _destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:102:25)
    at IncomingMessage.destroy (node:internal/streams/destroy:64:5)
    at abortIncoming (node:_http_server:602:9)
    at socketOnClose (node:_http_server:596:3)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:709:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

El error simplemente se debía por el callback dentro de la función dns.look(),
la condición err === true, devolvía un error por el tipo de input que le estaba enviando FCC, en este caso bastó con solo quitar esa condición y solo dejando la comprobación por RegEx, de esta manera pasó todos los tests.